# Moment duration returning a negative value

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I am receiving time in two different forms from the api :
`2022-07-07T07:40:38.119027597Z` and `2022-07-18 11:56:40`

And I pass these values into a function the converts the values into the the difference of the value vs the current time and converting them into hours.
But sometimes the output of value is a negative number. But I am unsure of what value would cause a negative number so Im finding it difficult to figure out where the error in my function is.

What causes moment.duration() to return a negative value?

```
const formatTime = (lastContact: string) => {
  
  const time = moment.utc(lastContact);
  if (!time.isValid()) {
    return "";
  }

  let d = moment.duration(moment().diff(lastContact)).asHours();
  
  if (d < 1) {
    let mins = Math.round(moment.duration(moment().diff(lastContact)).asMinutes());
    return `(${mins} min ago)`;
  } else if (d < 48) {
    let hours = Math.round(moment.duration(moment().diff(lastContact)).asHours());
    return `(${hours} hours ago)`;
  } else {
    let days = Math.round(moment.duration(moment().diff(lastContact)).asDays());
    return `(${days} days ago)`;
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there a chance that `lastContact` is in the future?

Comment: Switch the object and the argument.  Instead of moment().diff(lastContact), try this: lastContact.diff(moment())